# Mapping image from cartesian to polar coordinates with imageR

Tags: r, image, image-processing, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

I am attempting to map a panoramic image into polar coordinates using imageR, but get strange results.

As an example, I would like to take a square panorama like this one (courtesy of [Flickr user gadl](http://www.flickr.com/photos/gadl/) ([Alexandre Duret-Lutz](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/%7Eadl/)) under CC BY-NC-SA and edited into a square):

[image: square panorama]

And remap it to something like this (which I've done in GIMP):

[image: polar coordinate remapping of square panorama]

I've gotten pretty close in imageR with this code:

```
library(imager)
pano <- mirror(load.image("pano_image.jpg"), "y") # mirroring the image to map to center
map.shift <- function(x,y) list(x = y*cos(x), y = y*sin(x)) # Here, y is the radius and x is theta
polar_pano <- imwarp(pano, map = map.shift)
plot(polar_pano)
```

But I get the strange result:

[image: imager output of polar coordinate mapped panorama]

I'm not sure why it is only mapping into one quadrant? (Note: I realize that the interpolation will be strange in this example--that is not the issue).
To confirm that this *should* work, here is a toy example:

```
library(ggplot)
test <- data.frame("val" = rep(100:1, each = 99), theta = rep(1:100, 99), r = rep(1:100, each = 99))
ggplot(test, aes(x = theta, y = r, col = val)) + geom_point()

# Now converting from polar to cartesian
test$x <- test$r*cos(test$theta)
test$y <- test$r*sin(teast$theta)
ggplot(test_p2c, aes(x = x, y = y, col = val)) + geom_point()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result only has one quadrant because the resulting transformation has both negative and positive values.

In your function, the result's top left is `(-400, -400)` and the bottom right is `(400, 400)`. Halve and add 200 to make it `(0, 0)` and `(400, 400)`.

Scale the trig parameters to go from `-pi` to `pi`.

For the bottom of the original image to become the center of the resulting circle,  `x` needs to be the variable inside the trig functions.

```
library(imager)

pano <- load.image("pano_image.jpg")
pano <- mirror(load.image("pano_image.jpg"), "y")

map_shift <- function(x, y) {
  list(
    x = y * cos((x - 200) / 400 * 2 * pi) / 2 + 200,
    y = y * sin((x - 200) / 400 * 2 * pi) / 2 + 200
  )
}

polar_pano <- imwarp(pano, map = map_shift)
plot(polar_pano)
```

[image: plot]